# Why would anyone use buffer overflow?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I bought the book "Hacking - The Art of Exploitation". One of its content is buffer overflow. I think I understand how they work, however, I do not understand why anyone would try that.

Let's pretend that I have a program which is unsafe. Any hacker could easily cause a buffer overflow. So what? Those hackers don't know which program it is, and even if they would, what could they do? They don't have my computer... Even if, they cannot start that program without logging in, right?

So basically my question is, in what situations would a hacker cause a buffer overflow? How would he do it? Via the Internet? And then what?

I hope I'm in the right place with this question. I really don't understand why it's such a big deal to have such an unsafe program.

Comment: You're in right place, but I think its too broad

Comment: Read wikipage [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) & [exploit (computer security)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_%28computer_security%29)

Comment: may be hacking your computer is not much deal..bt hacking some computer organization with some substantial data or hacking some data centre/router can be big deal.

Comment: Thye basic Idea is it allows a hacker to crash a program ... wikipedia stack_buffer_overflow has a list of some good notable examples for why this is prolematic

Comment: Once they've logged in they can get your application execute the code they put in the buffer. Best case they could make simply crash. In fact if your code is susceptible to buffer overrun, you could make it crash often in ways that are very hard to debug.

Comment: Isn't the answer to your question in exactly that book you bought?

Comment: Notice that in many countries hacking a computer is illegal (even if no actual harm is done). See e.g. in France the [Article 323 du Code Pénal](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006149839&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070719) which defines hacking as a criminal offense.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I don't plan to hack anyone but myself. Just for educational purpose. I just didn't know why people even try to cause a buffer overflow. Now I have some ideas.

Answer (score 5):

> Let's pretend that I have a program which is unsafe. Any hacker could easily cause a buffer overflow. So what? Those hackers don't know which program it is  and even if they would, what could they do? They don't have my computer... Even if, they cannot start that program without logging in, right?

If your computer is running a network-accessible service, or if it's reading data from the network (say, a web browser), the fact that an attacker doesn't have physical access to your computer doesn't matter. It's still vulnerable, and can be exploited remotely by getting you to load unsafe content.

Consider, for the purpose of example, a web browser which used a fixed-size buffer for the `src` attribute on images. (This is not a real vulnerability, but let's imagine it existed for the purposes of this example.) Someone could exploit your browser by getting you to visit a web page with some malicious content on it:

```
<img src="example.jpeg?AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<exploit code here>">
```

They could even end up injecting this code into web pages that you're likely to visit by running an advertisement containing that code, or by sending out a bunch of links in spam pointing to that page. There's all sorts of ways to end up triggering a buffer overflow that don't involve using the computer directly.